Docker Host Not Found
I have two docker containers running, one with a Tomcat, one with an H2 database.
To build the containers I use docker compose build with the following compose.yml:
services:
  tomcat:
    build: tomcat
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - my-network

  h2:
    build: h2
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge

This is the Tomcat container's Dockerfile:
FROM tomcat:10.1.28-jre21
COPY my-app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/my-app.war
COPY h2-2.3.232.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib/h2.jar
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

This is the H2 container's Dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:21
COPY h2-2.3.232.jar /usr/local/h2.jar
COPY startup.sh /usr/bin/startup.sh
WORKDIR /
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/startup.sh"]

This is how I start the H2 database with startup.sh:
#!/bin/bash

cd /usr/local
java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcpAllowOthers -webAllowOthers

Running docker network inspect docker_my-networkshows that both containers are connected to the network. The Tomcat and H2 database are both working, I checked it in my browser.
Running curl http://tomcat:8080 inside the H2 container works.
However, running curl http://h2:8082 inside the Tomcat container returns "Host h2 not found". Please, what am I missing?

You say "running curl inside the container"; how are you starting the container and "getting inside" it?  (If you just run docker-compose up tomcat, absent a depends_on: block, the h2 container won't start; you could also get an error like this if h2 exits.)

I use docker compose up to start the containers. Then docker exec -it docker-tomcat-1 and then I run curl http://h2:8082. This is when the error happens.

Is docker-tomcat-1 actually the name of the container?  Does docker compose exec tomcat curl http://h2:8082 behave any differently?

Yes, docker-tomcat-1 is the name of the container. Using your suggestion leads to the same error.

So apparently this is the correct behavior. If you try e.g. curl http://h3:8082 (notice h3) you get an error message along the lines of "Could not resolve host name 'h3'". I was eventually able to almost connect the Tomcat in the other docker container to the h2 database. I'm saying almost because the database connected to the Tomcat appeared to be empty while the database that I saw in my browser in the H2 console contained entries.
Moral of the story: Don't use H2 as the main database for your docker application (or maybe only in embedded mode). You have much more documentation and resources available when using database systems like PostreSQL or MySQL and you avoid a lot of pain (in my opinion).

ports section should be inside tomcat section. The correct docker-compose.yaml is below:
services:
  tomcat:
    build: tomcat
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - my-network

  h2:
    build: h2
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge


(While you're making changes like this, it's safe to delete all of the networks: sections; Compose will automatically create a network named default and attach both containers to it.  But I think this typographical fix is secondary to the described issue.)

My bad. I adjusted the code in the question. But that's not the reason for the error, unfortunately.
